# Azure Portal will not deploy a VM from image due to "No Plan" error

Tags: virtual-machine, azure

I'm trying to deploy a VM from a custom image on Azure. I'm using the portal and Azure CLI.

When I create a VM from a product in the marketplace, everything goes smoothly. When I capture an image of the VM (going through the deallocation and generalizing process), and then try to deploy a VM from that image, it fails while creating the VM due to a "no plan" error.

I've been troubleshooting and it seems I need a template and parameters json file to specify how to deploy, but the documentation on this is scarce and I'm unsure how to configure these files and what part of them is the "plan". I can take an existing VM/resource group and download the template.json and paramater.json files, but trying to create a new VM with these files fails.

Does anyone have experience with this or knows where adequate documentation is?

Here is an example of the template.json file:

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "networkInterfaceName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
        "type": "array"
    },
    "subnetName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualNetworkId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIpAddressName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIpAddressType": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "publicIpAddressSku": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineRG": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "osDiskType": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
        "type": "secureString"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
        "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
    "vnetId": "[parameters('virtualNetworkId')]",
    "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
},
"resources": [
    {
        "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
        "apiVersion": "2018-10-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "ipConfigurations": [
                {
                    "name": "ipconfig1",
                    "properties": {
                        "subnet": {
                            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                        },
                        "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
                        "publicIpAddress": {
                            "id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName'))]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "networkSecurityGroup": {
                "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
        "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
        "apiVersion": "2018-08-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "properties": {
            "publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
        },
        "sku": {
            "name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "hardwareProfile": {
                "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
            },
            "storageProfile": {
                "osDisk": {
                    "createOption": "fromImage",
                    "managedDisk": {
                        "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                    }
                },
                "imageReference": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/56640100-5e0e-4f37-9c73-d716e7306962/resourceGroups/Test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/Test-VM-image-20190423094722"
                }
            },
            "networkProfile": {
                "networkInterfaces": [
                    {
                        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "osProfile": {
                "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
                "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
            },
            "diagnosticsProfile": {
                "bootDiagnostics": {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "storageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]"
                }
            }
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {
    "adminUsername": {
        "type": "string",
        "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
    }
}
```

}

Here is an example of the parameters.json file:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "value": "westus"
    },
    "networkInterfaceName": {
        "value": "test-vm726"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupName": {
        "value": "TestVMnsg114"
    },
    "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
        "value": []
    },
    "subnetName": {
        "value": "default"
    },
    "virtualNetworkId": {
        "value": "/subscriptions/56640100-5e0e-4f37-9c73-d716e7306962/resourceGroups/Test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Test-RG-vnet"
    },
    "publicIpAddressName": {
        "value": "TestVMip568"
    },
    "publicIpAddressType": {
        "value": "Dynamic"
    },
    "publicIpAddressSku": {
        "value": "Basic"
    },
    "virtualMachineName": {
        "value": "Test-VM"
    },
    "virtualMachineRG": {
        "value": "Test-RG"
    },
    "osDiskType": {
        "value": "Premium_LRS"
    },
    "virtualMachineSize": {
        "value": "Standard_B2s"
    },
    "adminUsername": {
        "value": "clear"
    },
    "adminPassword": {
        "value": null
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
        "value": "testcustomacc282828"
    },
    "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
        "value": "/subscriptions/56640100-5e0e-4f37-9c73-d716e7306962/resourceGroups/Test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/testcustomacc282828"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I've learned a little more since posting. The "plan" information is only needed when deploying a marketplace solution, so since I'm deploying from a custom image I don't need it. However since I built my custom image on a marketplace solution, the template still has the marketplace solution as my base, and so it thinks I need a plan. I'm currently trying to build a custom ARM template to deploy my image, though that process is horrendously complicated and poorly documented.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the plan information like so:

```
    "imageReference": {
    "id": "/subscriptions/56640100-5e0e-4f37-9c73-d716e7306962/resourceGroups/Test-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/Test-VM-image-20190423094722",
    "publisher": "string",
    "offer": "string",
    "sku": "string",
    "version": "string"
  },
```

Even though it is a custom image, if it was built from a marketplace image it will still have the plan information tied to it.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/2019-03-01/virtualmachines

Comment: Those resources are the first and only ones I came across as well, but they don't help with my use case, since I am deploying from a custom image.

Comment: can you share your code so I can test?

Comment: I put example code in the original post. This was made the same way I made my original image, and gets the same error.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: So I should add the publisher, offer, sku, and version fields? My custom image doesn't have any of those properties. Did you test it and did that work?

Comment: Yes add the publisher, off and sku of the version you based your image off of. You can get the info using PowerShell if you don't know off the top of your head https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/cli-ps-findimage good to check using powershell anyways as sometimes the publisher and sku names can be a bit funky

Comment: When I do that I get an error that "The property 'imageReference.id' cannot be used together with property 'imageReference.publisher'". 

I believe I cannot use publisher information along with my custom image. The template uses this information to decide what to build the VM from, so I can't tell it to build from two different sources.

Comment: My issue has been solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55733411/how-to-fix-azure-portal-not-deploying-a-vm-from-image-due-to-no-plan-error?noredirect=1#comment98517067_55733411